# Bevel Tool on two combined rectangles

Tags: bevel

I want to apply the beveltool to this mesh:

[image]

To achieve a form like this:

[image]

But the rusult is this:

[image]

You see the gap between these to rectangles?

I want to get rid of that gap and i want a smooth inner corner (at the gap) but i don´t know how..

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

Scale a cube to a shape like in the first picture. Then cut a loop using the Loop Cut and Slide tool. (Picture 2.) Change the selection mode to Faces and select the end Face shown in picture 3. Press E to extrude, then drag away from the face to "pull out" a new section. Now you can use your bevel tool on the shape and there'll be no gap.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was so disappointed and depressed because i just didn´t know how to do it properly..